# How to integrate Elassandra in my Jhipster app by Docker Image?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, cassandra, jhipster, elassandra

I want to integrate elassandra in my jhipster app. In which i'm using cassandra as db.

i'm following the official elassandra installation process with docker image but their is confusion to understand which container_name have to add in which command.
here is official link: http://doc.elassandra.io/en/latest/installation.html#docker-image

and my port 9200 is not enabled

> > docker run --name some-elassandra -d strapdata/elassandra
> >
> > docker run --name some-app --link some-elassandra:elassandra -d app-that-uses-elassandra

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch ports 9200 and 9300 are exposed for communication between containers.

So when an elassandra container has been started like this :

`docker run --name some-elassandra -d strapdata/elassandra`

Contacting the REST API could be done with something like :

`docker run -it --link some-elassandra --rm strapdata/elassandra curl some-elassandra:9200`

If it still not working, be sure you pulled a recent version of the image, and feel free to open an issue on the github repository [strapdata/docker-elassandra](https://github.com/strapdata/docker-elassandra)

This elassandra image is based on the official [cassandra image](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/). You may refer to its documentation for advanced setup.